# Localised Text Automatically gets changed when I rewrite html file

Tags: java, html

I have a project where I create html file. After some calculation I read that html file replace one column value but I dont know why it disturbs my localised text.

e.g.
Step 1> I create html file which is like below 
[image]

Step 2> Then my project keeps running and after that I replace my this column of html file 
[image]

with this

[image]

Using code :
[image]

But I dont know why my language chars change like below:
[image]

Comment: Do not post screenshot as code, We aren't gonna type that in, provide your code please.

Comment: @SamzSakerz Which part u want , html code or java code.

Comment: Figured out answer by myself. I was using FileReader and FileWriter without specifying UTF-8 .So inplace of filereader user Reader fr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(objFile),"UTF-8"); and inplace of FileWriter used Writer fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(objFile),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);